# How to remove hyphens during fill-paragraph?

Tags: emacs, hyphenation

When I manually use `fill-paragraph` I would like to have emacs remove all previously inserted hyphenations (by others?). That means automatically replacing all `"-\n"` with `""`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can imagine that not working out well in some cases, however...

```el
(defadvice fill-delete-newlines (before my-before-fill-delete-newlines)
  "Replace -\\n with an empty string when calling `fill-paragraph'."
  (when (eq this-command 'fill-paragraph)
    (goto-char (ad-get-arg 0))
    (while (search-forward "-\n" (ad-get-arg 1) t)
      (replace-match "")
      (ad-set-arg 1 (- (ad-get-arg 1) 2)))))

(ad-activate 'fill-delete-newlines)
```

Comment: Cool. I had no idea that you can magically hook yourself into an existing function like that. Works fine so far.